# How do I make my Mac search usr/local/opt before usr/local/bin so that it will use the packages brew installed instead of the system packages?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'd like to use the packages that brew installs instead of the system packages. When I run `which git`, I get `usr/local/bin/git`, but when I run `brew --prefix git`, I get `/usr/local/opt/git`.

`echo $PATH` gives me `/usr/local/opt:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`.

My `.bash_profile` contains `export PATH="/usr/local/opt:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`, and `/etc/paths` contains

```
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

It seems to me that everything points to the fact that my Mac should be searching `/usr/local/opt` before `/usr/local/bin`, so why does `which git` return `/usr/local/bin/git`, and how do I fix this?

Comment: maybe a silly question, but... did you remember to `source ~/.bash_profile` after you updated it (or just start a fresh terminal session) ? I use the same setup you are describing and have never had a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both. Even tried restarting my computer completely. Any other ideas? I appreciate your input.

Comment: Your outputs are perfectly normal. `which git` gives you the path to the `git` *binary*, while `brew --prefix git` gives you the path to the `git` *directory*. `/usr/local/bin/git` *is* the `git` from Homebrew. You can verify this with `ls -l $(which git)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining what you mean by verify with `ls -l $(which git)`? I tried this and got `lrwxr-xr-x  1 wesleydashner  admin  30 Nov 19 13:50 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.24.0_1/bin/git`, and I don't understand what this is verifying.